# PHP Out of memory change memory size not helping

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I try change resize image with `imagecopyresampled`. Problem i have very big images it's 25 000px x 25 000px. I try it launch on localhost, me computer installed 8gb RAM. PHP i get error:

`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1844969472) (tried to allocate 86400 bytes)`

i try increase memory size in php.ini file: `memory_limit=6144M` and in php file: `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`  but it doesn't help

me code:

```
public function copyResample($pasteStartX, $pasteStartY, $startCopyX, $startCopyY, $dstWidth, $dstHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight, $outputPathToFileWOExt) {
    $dstImage = imagecreatetruecolor($dstWidth, $dstHeight);

    switch ($this->getMimeType()) {

        case 'image/jpg':
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->getPathToFile());
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            $srcImage = imagecreatefrompng($this->getPathToFile());
            break;

        case 'image/gif':
            $srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($this->getPathToFile());
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception("File is not an image, please use another file type.", 1);
    }

    imagecopyresampled($dstImage, $srcImage, $pasteStartX, $pasteStartY, $startCopyX, $startCopyY, $dstWidth, $dstHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

    switch ($this->getMimeType()) {

        case 'image/jpg':
        case 'image/jpeg':
            if (imagetypes() && IMG_JPG) {
                imagejpeg($dstImage, $outputPathToFileWOExt . "." . $this->getExt());
            }
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            if (imagetypes() && IMG_PNG) {
                imagepng($dstImage, $outputPathToFileWOExt . "." . $this->getExt());
            }
            break;

        case 'image/gif':
            if (imagetypes() && IMG_GIF) {
                imagegif($dstImage, $outputPathToFileWOExt . "." . $this->getExt());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A 25,000x25,000 pixel image requires 2,500,000,000 (2.5GB) of memory before you ever start resampling; the resample will require at least double that

Comment: PHP will be slow and will require a lot of memory for a such feature. Look forward to another solution. Imagemagick (from command line, not php) may be faster but you'll still need a lot of memory.

Comment: i try imagemagic with it not get result only running script and doesn't stop i wait 1 hour and don't get result.. if i have smaller image i get resutl fast..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fact is you're still running out of memory. A 25,000px x 25,000px pixel image is going to require a hell of a lot of memory - and double if you're doing a imagecopyresampled.